# How can i assign each new room object with its own list of item objects

Tags: c#, list, object

I'm trying to populate each `Room` i create with `InteractiveObjects` any work arounds? or do i need to make one list for each individual room? which i really don't like to do

```
class Room
{
    private string Name { get; set; }
    private string Description { get; set; }

    private static List<InteractiveObjects> RoomObjects { get; set; } = new List<InteractiveObjects>();

    InteractiveObjects woodenDoor = new InteractiveObjects()
    {
        Name = "Wooden Door",
        Description = "Looks like it's not very durable",
        Type = "Door",
        Breakable = true,
        FitsInInventory = false,
        Locked = true
    };

    public static Room SmallRoom = new Room()
    {
        Name = "Small Room",
        Description = "it's a small room with only one wooden door and a ceiling light",
        //RoomObjects.Add(woodenDoor) DOES NOT WORK
    };
    public static Room Cellar = new Room()
    {
        Name = "Cellar",
        Description = "Some Description",
        //RoomObjects.Add(someObject) DOES NOT WORK
    };
}
```

Comment: If each room has it's own list, or the list might be different for each room, that that is, in fact, an list on each instance. In that case, you each room needs its own list.

Why do you "really not like to do" that?

Answer (score 2):

Remove **static** from RoomObjects to make it instance field.

Answer (score 2):

Your first problem is that `RoomObjects` is declared as `static`, so you use the same `List<InteractiveObjects>` instance for all `Room` instances.

The second is just a wrong syntax. You cannot explicitly call `Add` in an object initializer. But the compiler transforms this syntax into calls to `RoomObjectsAdd`:

```
public static Room Cellar = new Room()
{
    Name = "Cellar",
    Description = "Some Description",
    RoomObjects = { someObject1, someObject2 }
};
```

Comment: @sokkyoku edited the answer, you cannot explicitly call a method on a property inside an object initializer, no matter if the property is static or not.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you need your `RoomObjects` list for. Should it contain for a given `Room` the `InteractiveObjects` that belong to that `Room` or should it contain a list of all `InteractiveObjects` that are used regardless of their `Room`?

If as your title suggests you want each `Room` to have a list of only that `Room`s items then you will need a List per room, and you'll have to remove `static` from `RoomObjects` definition.